# Balde - setup problems

Tags: c, apache, fastcgi, glib, balde

I am trying to setup Balde (http://balde.io).

I referred [their docs](http://docs.balde.io/getting-started.html), downloaded the latest stable release, installed fastcgi dev kit and apache with mod fcgi.

Then I built balde.

Then I tried the example and compiled it with `` gcc hello.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags balde` -o hello ``

Then I set the following site-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName https://${C9_HOSTNAME}
    ScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/workspace/try/hello/
    <Directory /path/to>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options ExecCGI
        SetHandler fcgid-script
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also the permission of `hello` is 777 (temporarily)

Yet I get 403 Forbidden when I visit https://balde-meghprkh.c9.io/ . Can you tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change `<Directory /path/to>` to `<Directory /home/ubuntu/workspace/try>`. This should fix your issue

Comment: Yet I get the same error. If you want to access my box see https://ide.c9.io/meghprkh/balde and clone it but its okay if you can just provide me some assistance

Comment: Does it have something to do with cloud9 or using https ?